# auto open bootstrap modal on page load for 3 times every user

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

i need that bootstrap modal to be shown on page by loading the page and i found the following code. but there are two issue:

1- i want that modal to be shown for 3 times for every user, not just for first time! how can i solve that, my friends?
2- i need to show that modal on many specific pages. how can i control that?

my JS codes:

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1){
    // load the overlay
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});

    var year = 1000*60*60*24*365;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + year);
    document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();

  }
});
```

my HTML codes:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;" >Download on app store</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12"><img src="" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2"><img src="" class="img-responsive" /></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!--<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>-->
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

beforehan, thanks for helping

note: i am not familiar with java script and jQuery. would you make my codes correctly in the answer?

Comment: on document ready OR load open modal popup and store increament count in localstorage or cookie, and check count before open popup.

Comment: @Devsi Odedra  i am not familiar with java script and jquery. can you repair my codes above?

Comment: place your all code here  html + jquery

Comment: @Devsi Odedra i added them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several months, I Found the answer myself. so please check my new question:
[how to set cookie after 10 seconds by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61661918/how-to-set-cookie-after-10-seconds-by-javascript)
.
In my answer (that question), you can see the solution of this qustion.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like below.**

```js
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var count = 0;
  
  /*if(localStorage.getItem("modal_count")  === null) {
   
  } else {
     count = localStorage.getItem("modal_count");

  }*/

count = count+1;
//if(count <= 3) {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');

 // localStorage.setItem("modal_count", count);
 //}

});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <button type="button" id="open_modal"> sample button</button>
  </body>
  </html>
  
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;" >Download on app store</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12"><img src="" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2"><img src="" class="img-responsive" /></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!--<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>-->
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks my friend, but storing increament count in localstorage is better or in cookie? if i did this change: `if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') <= 3){` in my own JS codes, it is true too?

Comment: you can set expiry time for the cookie, but for local storage you need to remove it manually, so you can choose as per your need.

Comment: you mean my change is true too? i mean: `if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') <= 3){` without changing expiry time for the cookie in that code. i changed `('visited=true') == -1)` to `('visited=true') <= 3)`

Comment: it is only for reference, you can use your cookie code.

Comment: Hi my friend. Would you help me how to use cookie in your code for show modal for 3 times every user?