# how to set cookie after 10 seconds by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I need you really to solve this issue. I tried several ways but  my mind does not work anymore. I made a function to set cookie in **JavaScript** but in that way, when the window loads, the cookie (`visit`) **immediately** will be set, but I need the cookie to be set **after 10 seconds** that user stay in page of website. would you help me, my freinds?
In addition by this code, I want to show a **Modal** and `hereiakarneta` is the **ID** of that Modal.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function getCookieVal(offset) {
        var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
        if (endstr == -1)
            endstr = document.cookie.length;
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
    }

    function GetCookie(name) {
        var arg = name + "=";
        var alen = arg.length;
        var clen = document.cookie.length;
        var i = 0;
        while (i < clen) {
            var j = i + alen;
            if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg)
                return getCookieVal(j);
            i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
            if (i == 0)
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    function SetCookie(name, value) {
        var argv = SetCookie.arguments;
        var argc = SetCookie.arguments.length;
        var expires = (2 < argc) ? argv[2] : null;
        var path = (3 < argc) ? argv[3] : null;
        var domain = (4 < argc) ? argv[4] : null;
        var secure = (5 < argc) ? argv[5] : false;
        document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
            ((expires == null) ? "" : ("; expires=" + expires.toGMTString())) +
            ((path == null) ? "" : ("; path=" + path)) +
            ((domain == null) ? "" : ("; domain=" + domain)) +
            ((secure == true) ? "; secure" : "");
    }

    function DisplayInfo() {
        var expdate = new Date();
        var visit;
        expdate.setTime(expdate.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 365));
        if (!(visit = GetCookie("visit")))
            visit = 0;
        visit++;
        SetCookie("visit", visit, expdate, "/", null, false);
        if (visit == 1) {
            $('#hereiakarneta').modal({ show: true });
        }
        if (visit == 2) {
            $('#hereiakarneta').modal({ show: true });
        }
        if (visit == 3) {
            $('#hereiakarneta').modal({ show: true });
        }
    }

    //window.onload = DisplayInfo
    $(window).on("load", DisplayInfo);

});
```

## HTML

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="hereiakarneta" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;" >Download on app store</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12"><img src="" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2"><img src="" class="img-responsive" /></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot to all of you

Comment: Write another function that does the delayed actions e.g. setting the cookie then can call [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) in DisplayInfo to call the new function with a 10 second delay.

Comment: @Rup I used the setTimeout() to show modal after 10 seconds but the issue is: when the user loads the page and leave it less than 10 second, the cookie will be set but the modal does not show to him. and consider that I want to show modal to user just for 3 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that I can not add +1 to cookie on live (without refreshing page) after 10 seconds. So I changes My question to show the modal (popup) by another way. so please see the new question:
[How to Add +1 to a cookie value on click of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61693712/how-to-add-1-to-a-cookie-value-on-click-of-a-button/61693766?noredirect=1#comment109126833_61693766)

Before changing my question, I used the following code with `setTimeout()` but the problem was: when the user open one page, immediately the cookie will be set and after 10 seconds the modal will be show, so when the user before 10 second leave the page, one of those 3 times I want to show him the modal will be lost :| I needed that when a user open the page, after 10 seconds the cookie be set and when the use leave the page before 10 seconds, the cookie not be set.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function getCookieVal(offset) {
        var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
        if (endstr == -1)
            endstr = document.cookie.length;
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
    }

    function GetCookie(name) {
        var arg = name + "=";
        var alen = arg.length;
        var clen = document.cookie.length;
        var i = 0;
        while (i < clen) {
            var j = i + alen;
            if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg)
                return getCookieVal(j);
            i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
            if (i == 0)
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    function SetCookie(name, value) {
        var argv = SetCookie.arguments;
        var argc = SetCookie.arguments.length;
        var expires = (2 < argc) ? argv[2] : null;
        var path = (3 < argc) ? argv[3] : null;
        var domain = (4 < argc) ? argv[4] : null;
        var secure = (5 < argc) ? argv[5] : false;
        document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
            ((expires == null) ? "" : ("; expires=" + expires.toGMTString())) +
            ((path == null) ? "" : ("; path=" + path)) +
            ((domain == null) ? "" : ("; domain=" + domain)) +
            ((secure == true) ? "; secure" : "");
    }

    function DisplayInfo() {
        var expdate = new Date();
        var visit;
        expdate.setTime(expdate.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 365));
        if (!(visit = GetCookie("HereIsKarneta")))
            visit = 0;
        visit++;
        SetCookie("HereIsKarneta", visit, expdate, "/", null, false);
        //var message;
        if (visit < 4) {
            //$('#hereiakarneta').modal({ show: true });
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#hereiakarneta').modal({
                    show: true
                })
            }, 2000);
        }
        if (visit >= 4) {
            $(".dologinfirst").delay(2000).fadeIn(500);
            $("#menubutton").click(function(){
                $(".dologinfirst").hide();
            });
            $('body').click(function() {
                $(".dologinfirst").hide();
            });
        }
    }

    //window.onload = DisplayInfo
    $(window).on("load", DisplayInfo);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a timeout to your page's load-event like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.cookie = "hasBeenHereFor10Seconds=true";
  },10000)
});
```

Comment: I used the setTimeout() to show modal after 10 seconds but the issue is: when the user loads the page and leave it less than 10 second, the cookie will be set but the modal does not show to him. and consider that I want to show modal to user just for 3 times

Comment: and How can I use that in my code? would you complete my code. thanks

Comment: That is not the intended use of Stackoverflow, I guess...

Simply use setTimeout to do three things after 10 seconds: 

1) Show the modal if your counting cookie is not set or less than three
2) At the same time create the cookie with value = 1 OR
3) At the same time update the cookie with value = cookie's value + 1

Comment: thank you a lot but asked you to help because I am not in good condition. in addition, I need the cookie (visit) to be set after 10 seconds every time. not on time set `hasBeenHereFor10Seconds=true` and then... I mean every time page loads, when 10 seconds last, the cookie count